# Blazor WASM DevOps CI Pipeline - Selecting one UI Project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, blazor-webassembly

In my solution, I have 2 Blazor WASM projects a FronendPrivate and FrontendPublic. I need to create 2 different CI Pipelines.

I create a task in my Azure DevOps CI pipeline

```
 variables:
        buildConfiguration: 'Release'
        buildVersion: 1.0.$(Build.BuildId)
        framework: net7.0
// Note these are part of the code
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Dotnet Publish'
        inputs:  
          command: publish
          projects: '**/EventManagement.UI.csproj'  
          publishWebProjects: true
          arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) -f $(framework) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

The problem I am having is not using the project section, it trying to publish both and getting sucked. Its been running for 40 mins now

```
Optimizing assemblies for size may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
Optimizing assemblies for size. This process might take a while.
```

What can I do to fix this?